# SQL filter query, Cannot get the correct output as i am looking for

Tags: asp.net, sql

This is the query in ASP.net SQL Database:

```
SELECT OpenWorkWeek, COUNT(Validation) AS Invalid, COUNT(Validation) AS Valid
FROM Email
GROUP BY OpenWorkWeek, Validation
ORDER BY OpenWorkWeek
```

Output:

```
WorkWeek Invalid Valid
-----------------------    
WW 01       4      4
WW 01      52     52
WW 02      21     21
WW 02     231    231
```

The result that I want to show should be something like this:

```
WorkWeek Invalid Valid
------------------------    
WW 01       4      52
WW 02      21     231
```

Please help on the query!

Thank you! :)

Comment: plz format the output properly else create a sample sqlfiddle! and in your query both Valid & Invalid columns have same 'Validation' column! dont u think it must be different? Which will return same output!

Comment: Please **explain in plain English** how you want to get from the current output to the desired output - what do you want to do, which rows do you want to keep, which do you want to discard - what's the **criteria** for this decision??

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: You have the values Valid and Invalid. How do you know if Validation is Valid or Invalid? Currently you are displaying the same Validation value twice.

Comment: Looks like just changing one of the count

Comment: I know it's displaying validation value twice and for that I am not sure how to remove it. The valiation is having 2 value which is valid and invalid. What i wanted is show the result in the same row with workweek 01 and return 2 value on different column. Like i shown on above

Comment: How do u decide __VALID__ & __INVAID__ ? Just changing __Alias__ doesnt do that isnt it?

Comment: By changing the alias is for showing the column title only.
I wanted something the result like this:

SELECT OpenWorkWeek, COUNT(Validation) AS Invalid, COUNT(Validation) AS Valid
FROM Email
**WHERE Valid = 'valid' AND Invalid = 'invalid'**
GROUP BY OpenWorkWeek, Validation
ORDER BY OpenWorkWeek

The thing is I cannot call the where function like that because it's wrong but I just don't know how to change it.

Comment: are u ok? you are inserting the __NUMERIC__ values and trying to compare '__String__' values! how is it possible for non existing columns? And one more thing to NOTICE you all you are writing __COUNT()__ it must show the count of __COLUMN VALUES__ and not the single value. Please see the required output  added by __OP__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to post The values of `Validation` `Column`, So that we can Get the `Count` Values of `Validation`.

For Example, Consider `Validation` has the values Like

```
Validation
----------
Valid 
InValid
InValid
Valid
Valid
```

So the query would be

```
SELECT OpenWorkWeek, SUM(Case When Validation = 'Valid' Then 1 Else 0 End) AS Valid,   
       SUM(Case When Validation = 'InValid' Then 1 Else 0 End) AS InValid
FROM Email
GROUP BY OpenWorkWeek
ORDER BY OpenWorkWeek
```

The Output Would be

```
WorkWeek Invalid Valid
------------------------    
WW 01       4      52
WW 02      21     231
```

You can replace case statement based on `validation` values

**Edit**

To get the Division result of Valid And Invalid try like this.

```
SELECT OpenWorkWeek,Valid,Invalid, (Cast(Valid As Decimal)/ Cast(InValid As Decimal)) As Percentage
From
   (
    SELECT OpenWorkWeek, SUM(Case When Validation = 'Valid' Then 1 Else 0 End) AS Valid,   
           SUM(Case When Validation = 'InValid' Then 1 Else 0 End) AS InValid
    FROM Email
    GROUP BY OpenWorkWeek
    ORDER BY OpenWorkWeek
   )Tmp
```

Comment: What if i want to divide the 2 sum value? like invalid / valid. How can I do so?

Comment: something like invalid divide by valid.

Example: 4 / 52 = 0.769%

Answer (score 1):

If you want result records per working week, you should group by working week, not by working week plus validation. To get valid and invalid counts, simply sum with a 1 for each match. In your comments you say Validation is either 'valid' or 'invalid', hence:

```
SELECT OpenWorkWeek, 
  SUM( CASE WHEN Validation = 'invalid' THEN 1 END ) AS Invalid
  SUM( CASE WHEN Validation = 'valid' THEN 1 END ) AS Valid
FROM Email
GROUP BY OpenWorkWeek
ORDER BY OpenWorkWeek;
```